# Python Read Variable

Tags: python, networking

I have a python script that reads switch hostnames from a txt file (cisco_input.txt) and runs commands on each switch.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    username = raw_input('Enter Your username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('Password:')


    ip_file = "cisco_input.txt"
        #LOG FILE NAME
    sys.stdout = Logger("cisco_output.txt")
    with open(ip_file) as bf:
        ip_list = bf.read().splitlines()
    for ip in ip_list:

        #START LOOP TO LOGIN TO DEVICES
        # Create instance of SSHClient object
        remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()

        # Automatically add untrusted hosts 
        remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
             paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        # initiate SSH connection
        remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
        # print "SSH connection established to %s" % ip

        # Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
        remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
        # print "Interactive SSH session established"

        # Strip the initial router prompt
        output = remote_conn.recv(500)

        # Turn off paging
        disable_paging(remote_conn)

        #COMMANDS TO SEND
        time.sleep(1)
        remote_conn.send("\n")
        remote_conn.send("en\n")
        remote_conn.send(password)
        remote_conn.send("\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        remote_conn.send("show interfaces counters errors | in 1/0/22\n")
        time.sleep(3)
        remote_conn.send("logout\n")
        time.sleep(.5)
        output = remote_conn.recv(15000)
        print output
        #RESTART LOOP
```

However, I need to be able to read a second variable for the interface and I'm not sure how I would do that. This line is where I need to be able to call my second variable for the interface:

```
remote_conn.send("show interfaces counters errors | in $INTERFACE\n")
```

CLARIFICATION:
Currently, the script reads in the switch name to run the command on. So right now I have a text file that looks like:
switch1
switch2
switch3

This works great when the port I need to run the command on stays the same. But the port is going to be changing for every switch.

So I'd need an input like:
switch1 Gi1/1
switch2 Gi1/15
switch3 Gi1/20

Then I need to be able to use the interface as a variable for the command I'm sending:
    remote_conn.send("show interfaces counters errors | in $INTERFACE\n")

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is your input and what is your expected output? E.g., what do the file contents look like and what do the contents of the wanted variables look like?

Comment: Do you mean something like `cmd = "show interfaces ... {}\n".format(switch_name)`? Where `switch_name` is set earlier?

Comment: added some clarification. Eric@ - The switch name is only used to SSH into the device. I would need format(interface) but not sure how to input that from the file to the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you format your file like this (csv, comma-separated value):

```
switch1, Gi1/1
switch2, Gi1/20
etc...
```

You can then read it in using [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
with open(file) as bf:
    reader = csv.reader(bf)
    ip_list = list(reader)

for switch, interface in ip_list:
    # use switch and interface
```

There is a problem with this however. If your file is large, loading it into memory all at once can be problematic. The following approach ditches the list and just iterates over the csv.reader, only loading into memory a single row at a time.

```
with open(file) as bf:
    reader = csv.reader(
    for switch, interface in reader:
        # use switch and interface
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse. That has extremely helpful